# Will my dwarf peach tree do fine in just afternoon sun

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, plant-recommendations, sunlight, peaches

I recently bought a dwarf bonfire patio peach and have it in only afternoon sun from 1-6pm but because I live in an apartment I only can either leave it where it is or move it to the front of the apt that gets morning sun from 6am to around 1pm. Where should I put it ?

Comment: What part of the world are you in? And its not clear whether this peach tree will be outdoors or in the apartment, please clarify...

Comment: Here's a related question: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24211/how-much-sun-do-peaches-need-to-fruit